# How to hide the native tooltip in IE when using jQuery Tooltip?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, tooltip, jquery-tooltip

Have a little problem again with my little application.
you can find it [here](http://www.mymobisite.be/victorpeeters).

In Chrome, Firefox, ... Everything runs fine.
In Internet explorer there's a little issue.

As i'm using jQuery UI ToolTip, the default tooltip may not be shown...
In Internet Explorer, it does appear anyway.

Somebody who knows how to fix this little problem?

Thanks!

Comment: its working in IE 9.0.12

Comment: @Swarnajith I can reproduce OPs error in the same browser. It is appearing sometimes and never - when 'Developer Tools' window is opened =)

Comment: This is most likely caused by the `title` attributes of the `area` elements. See Alex's answer for a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

I only may suggest do not use `title` attribute. You may use instead, for example, `data-title` attribute or any other name started with `data-`. After that specify required attribute using `items` option of plugin:

```
$('area').tooltip( { items: 'area[data-title]' } );
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't show any Tooltip at all if I set the attribute data-title, and the items option...

Comment: Could you provide sample of your code on jsfiddle.net? I suspect that it is just matter of correct selector for 'items'.

Answer (score 0):

@Alex G.P.
When I only used the "items" option, it didn't show anything at all.
I had to add a "content" option as well:

`$("area").tooltip({
    track: true,
    items: "area[data-title]",
    content: function () { return $(this).attr("data-title")}
});`

Now it works fine:)
Thank you anyway!